# Can't use SQLAlchemy model object in view

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to pass SQLAlchemy model to the View:

```
class Bandwidth(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bandwidth'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ping = db.Column('ping', db.Integer)
    download = db.Column('download', db.Float)
    upload = db.Column('upload', db.Float)
    timestamp = db.Column('timestamp', db.DATETIME)

    def __init__(self, ping, download, upload, timestamp):
        self.ping = ping
        self.download = download
        self.upload = upload
        self.timestamp = timestamp
```

I get data from db and pass it to the view by:

```
list = Bandwidth.query.all()
return render_template('index.html',list=list)
```

And than finally it fails in view while trying to execute:

```
{% for item in list %}
   <tr>
     <td>{{ item.timestamp.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M') }}</td>
     <td>{{ '%s' % item.ping }}</td>
     <td>{{ '%0.2f' % item.download }}</td>
     <td>{{ '%0.2f' % item.upload }}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Error that occurs is: **TypeError: <__main__.Bandwidth object at 0x7494c7f0> is not JSON serializable**

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize the model.

```
class Bandwidth(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bandwidth'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ping = db.Column('ping', db.Integer)
    download = db.Column('download', db.Float)
    upload = db.Column('upload', db.Float)
    timestamp = db.Column('timestamp', db.DATETIME)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'ping': self.ping,
            ...
        }

from flask import jsonify
list = Bandwidth.query.all()
serialized = [item.serialize for item in list]
return render_template('index.html',list=serialized)
```

Comment: I assume that in the last row it must be jsonify(serialized). But I still have an error in the view. TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

Comment: I just removed jsonify and changed last line to return `render_template('index.html',list=serialized)` and it's working like a charm. Thx on advice.